# Efficient multithreaded array building in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have many threads adding result-like objects to an array, and would like to improve the performance of this area by removing synchronization.

To do this, I would like for each thread to instead post their results to a ThreadLocal array - then once processing is complete, I can combine the arrays for the following phase. Unfortunately, for this purpose ThreadLocal has a glaring issue: I cannot combine the collections at the end, as no thread has access the collection of another.

I can work around this by additionally adding each ThreadLocal array to a list next to the ThreadLocal as they are created, so I have all the lists available later on (this will require synchronization but only needs to happen once for each thread), however in order to avoid a memory leak I will have to somehow get all the threads to return at the end to clean up their ThreadLocal cache... I would much rather the simple process of adding a result be transparent, and not require any follow up work beyond simply adding the result.

Is there a programming pattern or existing ThreadLocal-like object which can solve this issue?

Comment: You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of ThreadLocal array and use your result object as key in map.

Comment: Just have each thread produce "result-like objects" which include where those objects should be inserted into the final array, e.g. include the array indices.

Comment: Is the number of results known in advance?  What is the impetus that causes a thread to be assigned the task of producing a result? A set of data present at the beginning?  random events arriving asynchronously?

Comment: @HankD Results are produced by a thread pool, so random results come from random threads. Some tasks can produce multiple results, so there will be an unknown number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `ThreadLocal` objects are designed to be *only* accessible to the current thread. If you want to communicate across threads you cannot use `ThreadLocal` and should use a thread-safe data structure instead, such as [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

For the use case you're describing it would be easy enough to share a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` between your threads and have them all write to the queue as needed. Once they're all done (`Thread.join()` will wait for them to finish) you can read the queue into whatever other data structure you need.